# Response doesn't wait for async function

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I found the aproach how to put the async function into a router endpoint and tried to implement it but not suceed. E.g. this link [zellwk.com](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-express/)

The server sends only empty string instead of a huge string that is on `snippet.host`.

```js
    async function downloadData(url) {
        const options = {
            'method': 'GET', 'url': url, 'headers': {}, formData: {}
        };
        let result = '';
        await request(options, function (error, response) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(response.body)
            result = response.body
        });
        return {error: 0, text: result}
    }
```

```js
    app.get('/token/:token', jsonParser, async function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.params.token) //Don't mind this token
        try {
            let message = await downloadData('https://snippet.host/xgsh/raw')
            res.send(message)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
    });
```

How to make it wait for the download?

## EDIT

I implemented `node-fetch` and got this:
`{"error":0,"text":{"size":0}}`
What did I wrong?

```
async function downloadData(url) {
    const result = await fetch(url)
    return {error: 0, text: result}
}

app.get('/token/:token', jsonParser, async function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.token)
    try {
        let message = await downloadData('https://snippet.host/xgsh/raw')
        res.send(message)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of fetch call the response body need to be parsed first which you are missing.

```
async function downloadData(url) {
    const res = await fetch(url)
    if (res && res.status != 200)
        throw new Error("status code other than 200 received")
    let json = await res.json()
    return {error: 0, text: json}
}

app.get('/token/:token', async function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.token)
    try {
        let message = await downloadData('https://snippet.host/xgsh/raw')
        // let json = await  message.json()
        res.send(message)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

i tried calling the api but every time it is returning 404 . so json cant be called in that case. but if 200 is returned then you call json and return that accordingly.

Comment: I had to use .text() instead of .json() and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can only usefully `await` a promise.

`request` doesn't return a promise, it takes a callback function instead.

This is one of the reasons that [`request` was deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) two years ago.

Replace `request` with something which supports promises such as [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), the [native fetch](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v17.5.0/#add-fetch-api) that was added to Node.js recently, or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: .. or `util.promisify` request

Comment: @PA. — Or not, because `request` is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: I used `node-fetch` but got `{"size":0}`. Plz see EDIT

Answer (score 1):

In case you must use `request` (eventhough it's deprecated); or in case you find a similar situation with a old function that doesn't return a promise; you can turn your `request` into a function that returns a promise.

Either write your own wrapper, in the form of

```
function requestPromise(options) {
  return new Promise( 
    (resolve,reject) => request(options, 
      (err,response) => if (err) reject(err) else resolve(response)));
}
```

or, given that request's callback is in the form of function(err,response), directly use `util.promisify`

```
async function xxxx(...) {
    try {
      ...
      let response = await util.promisify(request)(options);
      ...        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `request` isn't actually an `async` function that returns a `Promise`, you can create your own `async` version of `request`.

```
function asyncRequest(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(response)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Then in your project rewrite your `downloadData` function to be:

```
async function downloadData(url) {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    headers: {},
    formData: {},
  }

  const result = await asyncRequest(options)

  return { error: 0, text: result.body }
}
```